# Python facebook-sdk Graph api access error

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am using [Python facebook-sdk](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) to fetch users's posts in Facebook page.

In facebook Graph api explorer, the request went well:

```
Get .../coldplay/feed?limit=2
```

[image]

In my program, the request:

```
In [27]: graph = facebook.GraphAPI("...")
In [28]: posts = graph.get_object('coldplay/feed?limit=2')
```

report error:

```
GraphAPIError                             Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/ubuntu/<ipython console> in <module>()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/facebook.pyc in get_object(self, id, **args)
     97     def get_object(self, id, **args):
     98         """Fetchs the given object from the graph."""
---> 99         return self.request(id, args)
    100
    101     def get_objects(self, ids, **args):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/facebook.pyc in request(self, path, args, post_args)
    296         except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    297             response = _parse_json(e.read())
--> 298             raise GraphAPIError(response)
    299         except TypeError:
    300             # Timeout support for Python <2.6
```

If I request without "?limit=2", the program works well:

```
In [45]: graph = facebook.GraphAPI("...")
In [46]: posts = graph.get_object('coldplay/feed')                                        
In [47]: len(posts)
Out[47]: 2
```

So I want to know how to make the request: '.../feed?limit=2' works well for the Python facebook-sdk? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide `limit` as an argument other than a part of the object.

The definition of `get_object` is `def get_object(self, id, **args)` which means you need to provide as keyword args

In your case: `graph.get_object('coldplay/feed', limit=2)`